# ASP.net Core 2.1 Application works in debug but doesn't work in release (IIS 6.0)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I created a console application that has the code from that link with no modification to the application logic. the console application's name is "testingx86.exe" and the target platform is .net framework 4.0

`runconsoleapp()` is a method in one of the controllers in asp .net core 2.1 websites that takes two parameters for input and output file.  The method invokes the console application and passes the parameters. the web application creates the converted files in debug mode but it just invokes the console application and corresponding open office process and does nothing in release mode. I have tried giving permissions to various accounts.

**how to make the site convert the files in release mode also?**

```
internal static void runconsoleapp(string InputFilePath, string OutputFilePath)
{   
    System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
    var path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    process.StartIenter code herenfo.WorkingDirectory = path;
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = $"/c testingx86.exe {InputFilePath} {OutputFilePath}";
    process.Start();
}
```

The links contain the code to convert office documents to pdf using C# and open office.

http://abdulmunim.com/how-to-convert-office-documents-to-pdf-using-open-office-in-csharp/